# Plot data with number and letters using gnuplot

Tags: plot, ssh, gnuplot

I have to plot data from .dat file in which the table structrure is:

```
time 62164.434123 N+001.312 N+001.123 N+001.412
time 43242.432423 N+002.432 N+001.136 N+001.812
```

This .dat file is taken through ssh.

How can I plot a X/Y plot in which X is the first number and Y is one of the other numbers at each raw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
plot '<sed "s/time \(.\+\) N+\(.\+\) N+\(.\+\) N+\(.\+\)/\1 \2 \3 \4/" file.dat' u 1:2 w lp,"" u 1:3 w lp,"" u 1:4 w lp
```

Comment: or maybe just `sed 's/N[+]//g'` ?